# Composition factors of two groups are the same up to permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that the composition factors of the composition series of $S_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ have the same composition factors up to permutation. I was given this problem and was just asked to find a composition series for each of the two groups, and then was told to show that the two groups have the same composition factors up to permutation. I found the composition factors but did not know how I should proceed to show this. What is the way to do this?

Comment: Well, a group with prime order must be cyclic..

Comment: @Berci What I did to claim I showed this, was I gave a composition series for each of the groups $\langle 0 \rangle \leq \langle 2 \rangle \leq \langle 1 \rangle$ and ${1} \leq A_3 \leq S_3$ then I showed the first two composition factors in each series were isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_3}$ and last two to $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and claimed that solved the problem, however I did not think this was correct.

Comment: This is wrong right? I felt like to answer the question I would have needed to know all of the composition series, not just one for each group.

Comment: No, it's correct. What does make you uncertain? $2\cdot 3=6$, we don't have many possibilities... Actually, using Cauchy theorem, this generalizes to arbitrary groups of size $pq$ where $p,q$ are primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe, for $\mathbb Z_6,$ we can have two composition series:
$$\mathbb Z_6 \trianglerighteq \mathbb Z_6 / \langle 3 \rangle \cong \mathbb Z_2 \trianglerighteq \{e\}$$
$$\mathbb Z_6 \trianglerighteq \mathbb Z_6 / \langle 2 \rangle \cong \mathbb Z_3 \trianglerighteq \{e\}$$
By Jordan-Holder program, we know these to have equivalent composition factors. In particular,
$$\{ \mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_3 \}$$
which are cyclic groups of prime order and therefore simple. Similarly, considering $S_6,$ we see
$$S_3 \trianglerighteq A_3 \cong \mathbb Z_3 \trianglerighteq \{e\}$$

which has the composition factors
$$\{ S_3 / A_3 \cong \mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_3 \}$$

Therefore, the composition series for both groups are equivalent under their composition factors.